# Accessing objects in typescript and find the highest key and value of it

Tags: javascript, object

```
this.maxObj = {
    "item": {
        "id": 29842,
        "interestName": "Pre-engagement ring",
        "audienceSize": "980460",
        "femaleAge18_24": "22",
        "maleAge18_24": "11",
        "femaleAge25_34": "25",
        "maleAge25_34": "9",
        "femaleAge35_44": "11",
        "maleAge35_44": "2",
        "femaleAge45_54": "7",
        "maleAge45_54": " 1",
        "femaleAge55_64": "6",
        "maleAge55_64": " 1",
        "femaleAge65plus": "5",
        "maleAge65plus": "  0",
        "gendermale": "24.6",
        "genderFemale": "75.4",
        "isActive": true,
        "createdAt": "2021-03-22T07:01:21.000Z",
        "updatedAt": "2021-03-22T07:01:21.000Z",
        "deletedAt": null
    },
    "refIndex": 21534,
    "score": 0.6113547101723916
}
```

Consider the above object. First, I write an "if condition" on `genderMale` and `genderfemale` to compare the values. I find `genderfemale` is greater. So my question is as follows: if `genderFemale` is greater I should select all the `femaleAge` (`femaleAge18_24`, `femaleAge25_34`, `femaleAge35_44`, `femaleAge45_54`,`femaleAge55_64` and `femaleAge65plus` from the object and find the highest among it. If `genderMale` is greater then it should find the highest value of `maleAge`.
the final answer should be `femaleAge25_34: "25"`.

Answer (score 0):

Considering your object structure, you can iterate through all keys of your object by using `Object.keys()`. Doing so, you will be able to compare the key to any substring by using `String.indexOf` or something similar and add their values to an array. Finally, check everything within that array using `Math.max()` and you're good to go.

```
const items = this.maxObj.item;
let arr = [];

Object.keys(items).forEach((key) => {
  if (key.includes(anySubString)) {
    arr.push(items[key]);
  }
});

// Adjust this one. Example is just taken from MDN
// https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max
const max = arr.reduce(function(a, b) {
  return Math.max(a, b);
});
```

Comment: i recive this error core.js:4197 ERROR TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object
    at Function.keys (<anonymous>)
    at SafeSubscriber._next (recommendation.component.ts:991)
    at SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub (Subscriber.js:183)
    at SafeSubscriber.next (Subscriber.js:122)
    at Subscriber._next (Subscriber.js:72)
    at Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:49)
    at MapSubscriber._next (map.js:35)
    at MapSubscriber.next (Subscriber.js:49)
    at FilterSubscriber._next (filter.js:33)

Comment: Looks like my code was wrong. I wrote `this.maxObj.items` instead of just `item`.

Comment: I passed the string ' femaleAge ' inside includes. this fetches all the objects(both male and female ages)

Comment: the code u have typed will fetch only the keys